# Limit of the set $(f(ax),f(x)]$ as $x\to\infty$ and $f$ non-increasing

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Assume $f>0$ is non-increasing with $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ and $a\in(1,\infty)$. I assume that $$\limsup_{x\to\infty} (f(ax),f(x)] =\emptyset.$$ How can I prove it?

I know that I have to show that for any sequence $x_n\to\infty$
$$
\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\bigcup_{m\geq n} (f(ax_m),f(x_m)] = \emptyset,
$$
but I don't see how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

I think I could show that the indicator functions of such sets converge to zero by showing that for any $y>0$ I can find $n\in\mathbb{N}$ large enough such that $f(x_n)< y$, implying there is no element in the limit set (since $0\notin (f(ax_n),f(x_n)]$ for all $n$).

Edit: I also know, that the second approach is equivalent to the first, still, I would like to see how one can prove it using sets.

Edit2: An analogous proof in terms of the first limit definition would be to say $$\bigcup_{m\geq n} (f(ax_m),f(x_m)] \subset (0,f(x_n)]$$ so that if $y>0$ was in the intersection, we would have $y\leq f(x_n)$ for all $n$. Yet, since $f(x_n)\to 0$, there exists an $N$, such that $y>f(x_n)$ for $n\geq N$. That seems to be solid, right?

Comment: Have you tried simple cases, like $f(x)=\frac 1x$?

Comment: Yes I did, but since I was looking for an explicit way to show that the intersection must be empty that didn't help much. I think I managed to prove it in an other manner, see the edit to the question.

Comment: If $t$ belong to the $\limsup$, then $t\in (f(ax_{k'}),f(x_{k'})]$ for all $k'$, where $k'$ form an infinite set of $\mathbb N$. In particular, we should have $t=0$, which is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument in Edit 2 is correct. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$